# REST APIs are working in postman and browser but not working when applied on project

Tags: rest, xamarin.forms

I have a strange problem.

I am working on a xamarin forms app. My REST APIs are working in postman and browsers, but when I apply these REST APIs to project they are not working. Already run many REST APIs in the project, but don't know why it is not working now. I am using the following code:

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        Debug.WriteLine("Enter here");
        var siteIdResponse = await client.GetAsync(My REST API);
        Debug.WriteLine("siteIdResponse:>" + siteIdResponse);
        if (siteIdResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
               //codes
        }
```

Output:

```
[0:] Enter here
Thread started:  #7
07-09 18:48:10.231 D/Mono    (21753): Image addref Mono.Security[0xb8ebcc80] -> Mono.Security.dll[0xb8e9be58]: 2
07-09 18:48:10.231 D/Mono    (21753): Prepared to set up assembly 'Mono.Security' (Mono.Security.dll)
07-09 18:48:10.231 D/Mono    (21753): Assembly Mono.Security[0xb8ebcc80] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
07-09 18:48:10.232 D/Mono    (21753): AOT: image 'Mono.Security.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/mnt/asec/com.pagematics.Business_App-1/lib/arm/libaot-Mono.Security.dll.so" not found
07-09 18:48:10.233 D/Mono    (21753): AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/Mono.Security.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/mnt/asec/com.pagematics.Business_App-1/lib/arm/libaot-Mono.Security.dll.so" not found
07-09 18:48:10.233 D/Mono    (21753): Config attempting to parse: 'Mono.Security.dll.config'.
07-09 18:48:10.234 D/Mono    (21753): Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.config'.
07-09 18:48:10.234 D/Mono    (21753): Assembly Ref addref System[0xb851f108] -> Mono.Security[0xb8ebcc80]: 2
07-09 18:48:10.234 D/Mono    (21753): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Security[0xb8ebcc80] -> mscorlib[0xb82cfaf0]: 58
Loaded assembly: Mono.Security.dll [External]
07-09 18:48:10.297 D/Mono    (21753): Assembly Ref addref System.Net.Http[0xb8e80b50] -> System.Core[0xb844e178]: 7
07-09 18:48:10.388 D/Mono    (21753): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0xb834d360] -> System[0xb851f108]: 15
07-09 18:48:10.790 I/Choreographer(21753): Skipped 100 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #8
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #9
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #5
The thread 'Unknown' (0x5) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #9
The thread 'Unknown' (0x9) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #2
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #10
The thread 'Unknown' (0x2) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Does it fail with an exception or error?  Does it crash?  Does it hang?

Comment: @Jason  The issue was with the device, when I debug the project with another device the REST APIs working perfectly. Tried Rebooting the device, but getting the same result.

Comment: @Jason All my REST APIs are starting with http. Still having the issue after changing the device. The REST API call is not happening, that is the real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the port. The port that I am using is not a public one.